# R - How to extract text between string and blank line?

Tags: r, regex, text, substring, blank-line

I am using `readLines` to read the content of the following text file:

```
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
* 7. Measured data                                                   *
*    And option to force measured LAI during simulation              *
*    (instead of using simulated values)                             *
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Observed phenology: only required if program DRATES is run!!
IDOYTR = 194    ! Day of transplanting (give 0 if direct-seeded)
IYRTR  = 1991  ! Year of transplanting (give 0 if direct-seeded)
IDOYPI = 240   ! Day of panicle initiation (give -99 if not observed)
IYRPI  = 1991  ! Year of panicle initiation (give -99 if not observed)
IDOYFL = 260   ! Day of flowering
IYRFL  = 1991  ! Year of flowering
IDOYM  = 288   ! Day of maturity
IYRM   = 1991  ! Year of maturity


*Leaf Area Index (m2 leaf / m2 ground):
LAI_OBS =
1991., 182.,  0.00 ,
1991., 194.,  0.028,
1991., 202.,  0.185,
1991., 211.,  0.325,
1991., 219.,  1.048,
1991., 240.,  3.680,
1991., 254.,  5.010,
1991., 260.,  4.628,
1991., 273.,  3.520,
1991., 288.,  1.938

*-- Parameter to set forcing of observed LAI during simulation
LAI_FRC = 0       ! No forcing 
*LAI_FRC = 2      ! Forcing
```

And I need to programmatically extract only the block of text identified by `LAI_OBS =`. The line number where `LAI_OBS =` is located varies from file to file. Therefore, I need to find a way to read all the text between the string `LAI_OBS =` and the next blank line.

So far I am using:

```
l <- readLines('file.txt')
which(obs.lai=='LAI_OBS =')
```

I can identify the initial line of the block I need to extract, but I don't know how to instruct R to go to the first blank line after `LAI_OBS =`.

The result I need is a data frame looking like this:

```
1991  182  0.00
1991  194  0.028
1991  202  0.185
1991  211  0.325
1991  219  1.048
1991  240  3.680
1991  254  5.010
1991  260  4.628
1991  273  3.520
1991  288  1.938
```

What is a convenient way to do this in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the index of the "LAI_OBS" (it looks like `==` can be used for in case if it is not a fixed case, then `grep` is more useful.  Then, get the index of blank elements with `nzchar`, select the first empty index which is greater than 'i1', get the sequence from 'i1' to 'i2' (after making adjustments i.e. adding 1 and subtracting 1), remove the extra characters using `sub/gsub` and read with `read.csv`

```
i1 <- grep("LAI_OBS =", l)+1
i2 <- which(!nzchar(l)) 
i3 <- i2[i2>i1][1]-1    
read.csv(text=gsub("\\.,", ",", sub("\\s*,$", "", l[i1:i3])), header=FALSE)
#    V1  V2    V3
#1  1991 182 0.000
#2  1991 194 0.028
#3  1991 202 0.185
#4  1991 211 0.325
#5  1991 219 1.048
#6  1991 240 3.680
#7  1991 254 5.010
#8  1991 260 4.628
#9  1991 273 3.520
#10 1991 288 1.938
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, your contribution to this community is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, the tricky part about your input file is being able to articulate where the input data ends.  One approach is to continue down your current path and use `which` again to match the following line:

```
*-- Parameter to set forcing of observed LAI during simulation

idx1 <- which(obs.lai=='LAI_OBS =')
idx2 <- which(substring(obs.lai, 1, 20) == '*-- Parameter to set')

df.keep <- obs.lai[idx1:idx2-1, ]
```

Note that if the file has multiple lines beginning with the 20 characters I attempt to match, you might have to increase the length of the substring.  My hunch is that the full line would be unique because it refers to `LAI` simulation.

Answer (score 1):

This works, not elegant but gets the job done:

```
l <- readLines('data.txt')
first <- which(l=='LAI_OBS =')
blanks <- which(l=='')
whichblank <- which(which(l=='') > first)
last <- blanks[whichblank]
first
last
```

outputs:

> [1] 18 [1] 29

Of course if there are more blank lines in the file you would just grab the first from `whichblank`